# Adding schema to text content in the loop, how?

Tags: the-content

Given the following code:

```
<?php 

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array(
        'class'=>'post_thumbnail_common', 
        'alt' => get_the_title() , 
        'title' => get_the_title(), 
        'itemprop'=>'image' 
        )
    );
    echo contentnoimg(41);
} else { 
    echo content(41); 
} 

?>
```

How can I add `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">` before `contentnoimg()` and `</div>` after it?

If I add it in the code, it breaks the syntax, because I can't use html in php code.

Comment: This is in the end a developer oriented site. If you can't change the code then you are asking a user oriented question, not a developer oriented one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them to `echo`

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail(
        'full',
        array(
            'class'=>'post_thumbnail_common',
            'alt' => get_the_title() ,
            'title' => get_the_title(),
            'itemprop'=>'image'
        )
    );
    echo '<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">'.contentnoimg(41).'</div>';
} else { 
    echo content(41);
} ?>
```